# Avoiding Spaces in Keywords

Tags: whitespace, language-design, compiler-theory

I am designing a language. I am being troubled by what to call "else if". My language uses indentation for blocks, so I need a keyword for "else if".

Python uses "elif" (meh...) and Ruby uses "elsif" (yuck!). Personally, I hate to use abbreviations, so I don't want to use either of these. Instead, I am thinking of just using "else if", where an arbitrary number of spaces can appear between "else" and "if".

I've noticed that this doesn't occur very often in programming languages. C# has "yield return" as a keyword, but that's the only example I can think of.

Is there an implementation concern behind this? I've created my lex file and it accepts the keyword with no issues. I am worried there is something I haven't thought of.

Comment: "yield return" isn't a keyword in C#. "yield" is a *contextual* keyword, which only has special meaning in some contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't allow inline comments/newlines, there's nothing wrong with multi-word keywords. The only thing is that `else if` might be confusing for your language users, tempting them to write `else while` or `else for`. You'll have hard time explaining them that your `else if` is a keyword and not two statements following each other.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, why bother having an "else if" keyword? You can just have an "else" keyword and the next thing is an expression... an "if" expression.

```
<expression> := IF | somethingelse
IF <expression> THEN <expression> ELSE <expression>
```

The idea being that the if in "else if" is just the start of the expression after the "else" keyword.

A sample of what I mean, per the comments

```
if (x == 1)
    return 5
else return 4

if (x == 1)
    return 5
else if (x == 2)
    return 6
else
    return 7
```

The concept above being that the `return 4` is no different than the `if` and it's "arguments". As long as you allot the start of the next command on the same line (even if it's not considered good form), you can treat the `if` in `else if` as just the start of the next expression.

Comment: My language will be yet another language that uses indentation to indicate a new scope. I don't want people to stick if statements and for loops all on one line, because that just gets nasty. I don't want to have to create a special case for else followed by if.